# AngularJS BarcodeScanner plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, barcode-scanner

I'm working on a cordova app with a barcode scanner.
I have already added the plugin with:
    cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
(it worked fine in my first app app but it was built on ionic framework, dunno if it have something to do with that)
So, when i just call:

```
function barcodeCtrl($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner)
{
    $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
                alert(imageData.text);
                console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
                console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
    };
}
```

I have the error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=ordovaBarcodeScannerProvider

i've tryed to comment the content on the function, still the same, sound like a problem with the `$cordovaBarcodeScanner` injection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the **ng-cordova.js**?
  Check this out: http://ngcordova.com/docs/

Comment: Yeah, thank you i forgot the include and the ngCordova injection in the module as i was first on ionic and it was done when you create the project, but still same result.